# If $\tan(x)=2\tan(y)$ what is the relation between $x$ and $y$

Tags: trigonometry

We know that $\tan(x)=2\tan(y)$ and $x,y>0$. I am trying to get a visual understanding of how the vectors representing the respective angles will vary in relation to one another.

Comment: Try looking at the double angle formula for tan.

Comment: Draw a picture of two right triangles. The tangent of an angle is simply the length of the “opposite” side if the “adjacent” side has length $=1$.

Comment: in the double angle formula, one angle is twice of the other. Here the tan value of one is twice of other, one angle is not twice of the other.

Comment: If you draw a triangle with vertices (0,0), (1,0) and (1, tan(y)) that represents angle y. Now, if you double the 2nd value of the 3rd coordinate to be (1, 2*tan(y)), you represent angle x. So it's basically how high your vector is when it hits x=1